# Como faço para gravar um arquivo em c com nome de varias variáveis?

Tags: c

Bom dia. Estou com um problema para conseguir criar um arquivo que armazene a hora em que o usuário modificou um determinado programa, por exemplo:
Se o usuário executou o arquivo as 2h34min32s, quero gravar essa data num arquivo com esse formato"cliente_2_34_32.txt".
o cogido está abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

struct cliente{
 char nome[30];
 int cpf,cep;
};
void info(struct cliente *aux){
 int cpf,cep;
 printf("\n digite os dados:\n Nome:");
 gets(aux->nome);
 printf("\n CPF: ");
 scanf("%d",&cpf);
 fflush(stdin);
 printf("\n CEP: ");
 scanf("%d",&cep);
 fflush(stdin);
 aux->cpf=cpf;
 aux->cep=cep;
};
int main()
{
 time_t tempo;
 struct tm *tempoS;
 int n=0;
 struct cliente *vet,*aux;
 FILE *ptr;
 vet=(struct cliente*)malloc((n+1)*sizeof(struct 
 cliente));
 info(vet);
 int v,y=1;
 while(y){
    printf("\n Deseja continuar: 1- sim, outro numero- 
  nao");
    scanf("%d",&v);
    fflush(stdin);
    if(v==1){
        n++;
        vet=(struct cliente*)realloc(vet,(n+1)*sizeof(struct cliente));
        aux=&vet[n];
        info(aux);
    }else{
        y=0;
    }
}
free(vet);
tempo=time(NULL);
tempoS=localtime(&tempo);
char nome[]="vaca_%d.txt";

printf("cliente_%d_%d_%d",tempoS->tm_hour,tempoS->tm_min,tempoS->tm_sec);
ptr=fopen(nome,"w");
fclose(ptr);

return 0;
}
```

A tela de respota é essa:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria saber alguma forma de fazer o a frase do printf(cliente_17_14_43) seja o nome do arquivo txt.

Comment: O que acontece quando você executa o *cogido*? Dá algum erro? Se sim, já edita a pergunta e descreva-o. Se não dá erro, já edita a pergunta e descreve qual é o comportamento observado. Qual foi a resposta? Qual deveria ser? Chega a criar o arquivo? Com qual nome?

Answer (score 1):

você pode renomear o arquivo use a função *rename*

PROTÓTIPO:

```
int rename (const char *Caminho_com_nome_antigo, const char *Caminho_com_nome_novo);
```

Comment: Tentei esse caminho, mas o meu problema é em como fazer as variáveis do sistema se transformassem em apenas uma única frase, e ai fazer a gravação do nome no titulo do arquivo txt.

Comment: ja tentou converter para string e concatenar em uma só variável o nome ?

Comment: Vlw ai. Conseguir resolver seguindo seu conselho, fiz a string receber o nome formatado